# Why does `print()` insert an extra newline between multiple writes?

Tags: python

The following code writes two lines to file `days`:

```
with open('days', 'w') as file: 
    for i in ['mon', 'tues']:
        file.write(i)
```

However, when I print the lines iteratively, both lines end up being printed on the same line:

**Exmaple 1:**

```
with open('days', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)

# output:
# montues
```

I can use '\n' to visually separate the lines, but this causes an extra linebreak to be inserted by `print`:

**Example 2:**

```
with open('days', 'w') as file: 
    for i in ['mon', 'tues']:
        file.write(i + '\n')    # adding '\n'
        
with open('days', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)

# output:
# mon
# 
# tues
```

The extra linebreak comes from `print`'s `end` argument being set to `\n` by default, but then why isn't this linebreak also inserted in example 1?

Comment: `The following code writes two lines to file days:` Does it? I would expect it to write a single line: `montues`. I would take a look at the file you just wrote.

Comment: _I can use '\n' to visually separate the lines_ Where do you do that? When you are writing the test file?

Comment: @Mark I know they aren't the same. I'm asking why `print` inserts an extra linebreak when we print the result of multiple writes that end with a '\n' (example 2 in my post), but does not do the same if the writes don't end with '\n' (example 1).

Comment: @user51462, but you are not writing two lines to the file. You are writing one, which is why when you later read them and print them in `Exmaple 1` it prints a single line. When you add the `\n` to the file, now you need to deal with it when you read it because `print()` adds a newline by default (you can specify `end=''` to change that) or strip the new line from the input (which is the opposite of the step you did to add it when writing).

Comment: @tdelaney, sorry I had forgotten to add that bit, please see the annotated line in example 2.

Comment: One trick is to use repr to see exactly what you got. `print(repr(open('days').read()))`. You should see where the file level newlines are.

Comment: @Mark I see, but then why are we able to iterate over them as though they were separate lines?

Comment: @Mark my [textbook](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=IF4NEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA143&ots=dNOhFiq9Z9&dq=%22The%20extra%20line%20between%20David%20and%20Andrea%20is%20there%20because%20print%20starts%20a%20new%20line%20each%20time%20it%20encounters%20the%20'%5Cn'%20at%20the%20end%20of%20each%22&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q=%22The%20extra%20line%20between%20David%20and%20Andrea%20is%20there%20because%20print%20starts%20a%20new%20line%20each%20time%20it%20encounters%20the%20'%5Cn'%20at%20the%20end%20of%20each%22&f=false) seems to think of them as separate lines too.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, I had tried `repr` but since I was able to iterate over them, I was under the impression that they were separate lines internally.

Comment: What makes you think you are iterating over two lines in example 1? Your results print a single line when you don’t insert the newline  character into the file. Did you open the file and look?

Comment: @Mark I'm a dingus sorry, I didn't realise I was only iterating over the one line. I understand now that `find.write` does *not* start a new line.